# How to compare two distinct groups of data within the same pandas df while using a second df as reference?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following two dataframes:

```py
    data = {'ID1':['A3', 'A4'], 'ID2':['B2', 'B3']}
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

    data2 = {'ID1':['A3','A3','A3', 'A4', 'A4','A4', 'B2','B2','B2', 'B3','B3','B3'], 
             'Stock':['x','y','z','x','y','z','x','y','z','x','y','z'], 
             'Weight':[0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.15,0.05,0.07,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2]}
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

They look like this:

```py
print(df1)

      ID1 ID2
    0  A3  B2
    1  A4  B3

print(df2)

      ID1 Stock  Weight
    0   A3     x    0.20
    1   A3     y    0.10
    2   A3     z    0.30
    3   A4     x    0.20
    4   A4     y    0.10
    5   A4     z    0.15
    6   B2     x    0.05
    7   B2     y    0.07
    8   B2     z    0.20
    9   B3     x    0.10
    10  B3     y    0.30
    11  B3     z    0.20
```

I would like to tell python to search in df2 for each pair in df1 (A3 <-> B2 and A4 <-> B3) and perform the following operation:

For all of the stocks that the pair has in common, take the lowest of the two weights and add all the lowest weights together.

To illustrate this mathematically:

[image]

where "i" is the first term of the pair, "j" is the second term of the pair, "k" represents the stock, and "h" is the intersection of the stock holdings of the pairs.

For each pair defined in df1, I would like for python to iterate over every "k" that belongs to "h" in df2, perform the sum of the min, and then display the result for each pair into a third column if df1.

Note that in the actual data, each item (e.g. A2) shows up hundreds of times in df2 - once for each stock. However, the set of stocks that each member of the pair holds differ from one another. I am only interested in the stocks that both members of the pair hold.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to understand question and answer if you can also add expected output

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {"ID1": ["A3", "A4"], "ID2": ["B2", "B3"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {
    "ID1": ["A3", "A3", "A3", "A4", "A4", "A4", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B3", "B3", "B3"],
    "Stock": ["x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z"],
    "Weight": [0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.15, 0.05, 0.07, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2],
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


for A, B in zip(df1.ID1, df1.ID2):
    A_search = df2.loc[df2["ID1"] == A]
    B_search = df2.loc[df2["ID1"] == B]

    merged_search = pd.merge(A_search, B_search, on=["Stock"], how="inner")
    merged_search["multiplication"] = (
        merged_search["Weight_x"] * merged_search["Weight_y"]
    )

    print(merged_search)
```

The above will print:

```
  ID1_x Stock  Weight_x ID1_y  Weight_y  multiplication
0    A3     x       0.2    B2      0.05           0.010
1    A3     y       0.1    B2      0.07           0.007
2    A3     z       0.3    B2      0.20           0.060
  ID1_x Stock  Weight_x ID1_y  Weight_y  multiplication
0    A4     x      0.20    B3       0.1            0.02
1    A4     y      0.10    B3       0.3            0.03
2    A4     z      0.15    B3       0.2            0.03
```

Now, your question is a bit confusing on *where* you would like the multiplication to take place and so for the example above I simply multiplied the `weight` value for the two given `ID1`/`ID2` variables. However, you should be able to utilize the context of this answer to format how you would like the actual arithmetic to be.

Comment: thanks for the tip. That already helps, but let me try to clarify the problem:

The output that I am looking for is:


{"ID1": ["A3", "A4"], "ID2": ["B2", "B3"], "Output": ["0.32", "0.35"]}

The output of your code replicates each pair three times (for x, y, and z) and then performs the mathematical operation for each. Therefore, for each pair, your code prints three rows. 

What I would like to do is: to sum up the three outputs of each pair, to assign the result to a third column "Output" in df1 - without storing the three outputs of each pair in the local memory of my pc.